# SQL trigger multiple insert update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've been researching how to create a TSQL trigger that will handle multiple Update/Inserts.

We have data coming from multiple sources and my goal is to verify/correct that data before updating/inserting.

I wrote a trigger that works for single rows of data.

I'm struggling to figure out how to get it to handle multiple rows of data.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_GPTitleToGov]
ON [dbo].[GoverningPersons]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Title1 VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @UBI VARCHAR(9)
DECLARE @ETPID CHAR(4)
DECLARE @Ident INT

SET @Title1 = (SELECT Title1 FROM INSERTED)
SET @UBI = (SELECT UBI FROM INSERTED)
SET @ETPID = (SELECT [ETPID] FROM [entity] WHERE @UBI = [entity].[UBI])
SET @Ident = (SELECT Ident FROM INSERTED)

IF ((@Title1 = 'Executor') OR  (@Title1 = 'Incorporator'))
    BEGIN
        IF @ETPID IN ('0143', '0147', '0148', '0150', '0152', '0154')
        UPDATE GoverningPersons
        SET [Title1] = 'Executor',
            [Title2] = NULL,
            [Title3] = NULL,
            [Title4] = NULL
        WHERE Ident = @Ident;

        ELSE
        UPDATE GoverningPersons
        SET [Title1] = 'Incorporator',
            [Title2] = NULL,
            [Title3] = NULL,
            [Title4] = NULL
        WHERE Ident = @Ident;
    END
ELSE
    UPDATE GoverningPersons
    SET [Title1] = 'Governor',
        [Title2] = NULL,
        [Title3] = NULL,
        [Title4] = NULL
    WHERE Ident = @Ident;
END
```

I think what's throwing me is where to join the fields so I can check the data against data in a different table.

I've never written a trigger before, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_GPTitleToGov]
ON [dbo].[GoverningPersons]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE gp
    SET Title1 = CASE
             WHEN i.Title1 IN ('Incorporator','Executor')
                AND e.ETPID IN ('0143', '0147', '0148', '0150', '0152', '0154') THEN 'Executor'
             WHEN i.Title1 IN ('Incorporator','Executor') THEN 'Incorporator'
             ELSE 'Governor'
          END
       ,Title2 = NULL
       ,Title3 = NULL
       ,Title4 = NULL
FROM
    GoverningPersons gp
    INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON gp.Ident  = i.Ident
    LEFT JOIN entity e
    ON i.UBI = e.UBI


END
```

Triggers are **NOT** executed once per row but rather as a **set based** operation so executed **only ONCE** for the entire DML operation.  So you need to treat it like any other update date with join statement.  Only you can use the special `inserted` and `deleted` tables.  The above is an example of an update trigger and should provide you with some direction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out now!

Comment: I had no idea there was such a thing as a case statement. This is super!

Comment: @E.Powell A `CASE` _expression_ results in a value. There is no `CASE` _statement_. Sadly, Microsoft doesn't comprehend that and uses terminology at random in their "documentation".